# Firebase cloud messaging not working on safari

Tags: firebase, safari, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am encountering an error when attempting to configure Firebase Cloud Messaging on Safari. It works fine in Chrome, Firefox, and Edge. When attempting to configure Firebase, it throws the error message, "This browser doesn't support the APIs required to use the Firebase SDK.

I have read their documentation, which states that Safari doesn't directly support FCM. However, it can be enabled by using some polyfills.

Guide me on how to make FCM work in Safari using polyfills

Can someone suggests any work around to make FCM work on safari

[Error that I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ZlkL.png)